XmlParserException (XmlParserException: ">" expected at 77:21) in flutter
I got an error with SggPicture.network(). I displayed them on screen but throw error on debug console for per SvgPicture.newtork(). I had used flutter_svg package.

I saw flutter:

unhandled element <style/>; Picture key: Svg loader and XmlParserException (XmlParserException: ">" expected at 77:21).

Wrap(
      spacing: 0,
      runSpacing: 5,
      children: states.properties
          .map(
            (e) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.network(
                    "https://myAdrees.com/${e.logoGrey}",
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  CustomTextWidget(
                    text: e.tanim ?? '',
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    )

I checked about my code.

It's not mine file

what I should do. because it's file in flutter not in lib directory

I have no idea what you mean by "in flutter"

unhandled element <style/>: Either it is a start tag and therefore <style> or an ending tag and therefore </style>. It could also be an empty element and therefore not valid and could be removed.

You could use any XML validator to test if your SVG document is valid XML.
